# sort data.table by a column within each key

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with keys `x` and `y` and I want to sort by a column `z` within each key.

```
> DT
    x y          z
 1: a a  0.5526312
 2: a a  0.6339102
 3: a a -0.7490821
 4: a a -0.6850176
 5: a a  1.7943156
 6: a b  0.9271090
 7: a b  1.3936642
 8: a b  1.4815404
 9: a b -0.7850981
10: a b -1.0487700
11: b c  1.5184297
12: b c -0.4640705
13: b c -0.6513462
14: b c -0.5568319
15: b c  1.5422990
16: b d  0.8810654
17: b d -0.1895812
18: b d -2.6263378
19: b d  0.7371594
20: b d  1.4122076
```

My first attempt is `DT[order(z), .SD, by = list(x, y)]`, however, this does not keep the keyed columns sorted. I know I can do this in two steps:

```
DT <- DT[order(x, y, z)]
setkeyv(DT, c('x', 'y'))
```

However, this does not seem like a good practice because you are hoping the column `z` will remain sorted when the keys are being sorted. I also do not want to set `z` as key because it is not meant to be used as keys later on. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem if you leave the keys as `x,y,z`?

Comment: @Arun: it may not be a problem. I may join this data.table with other data.table keyed by only x and y, so I thought it might be a good idea to keep things simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not:

```
setkey(DT, x, y, z)
setkey(DT, x, y)
```

Use `setkey` to sort by all three columns, and then remove the last column from the key by resetting it.  Also, to address your concern about the sort being maintained, it is documented (2nd paragraph of Details section of  `data.table` documentation):

> The sort is stable; i.e., the order of ties (if any) is preserved.

This means that when you sort by `x` and `y`, *after* you have sorted by `x`, `y`, and `z`, the orders of `z` within any set of `x`-`y` values will be undisturbed because they all tie wrt to the `x`-`y` values

Comment: I actually thought about it, but wasn't sure if I should count on `z` still being sorted when the keys are reset.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure that the sort is stable.

Comment: What is the difference between setkey and setorder?

Comment: > Note that setkey still requires and will always sort only in ascending order, and is different from setorder in that it additionally sets the sorted attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the key including z and then unset it. It remains sorted by z within x and y but it is no longer a key.

```
setkey(DT, x, y, z)
setkey(DT, x, y)
```